# adj_timex call does not work

Tags: linux, time, linux-kernel, debian-based

`adjtimex` does not seem to have any impact on the system time.

I am running `Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2`. Stopped ntp, and ran the following multiple time, still could not find any time pull. It would be great if someone could shed some light this issue.

```
    int secs = 0, usecs = 500000
    timex_delta.offset= (secs * 1000000) + msecs;
    timex_delta.status= STA_PLL;
    timex_delta.modes = ADJ_OFFSET | ADJ_STATUS;
    c = adjtimex(&timex_delta);
```

Comment: What is the return value, `c`? Is it `5 == TIME_BAD`, i.e. *"clock not synchronized"*? If it is `-1`, then also report the `errno`.

Comment: c is coming as 0, regardless of how frequent I call the function.